# Trimming or converting a mysql date field with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying the contents of a datetime field in mysql in a table with php, and want to show just the date. Is there a way to convert or do this, or must the actual string be editied or trimmed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using strtotime...

A simple way is like this:

```
$date="2009-01-27 14:30:22";
echo strftime("%d %m %Y", strtotime($date));
```

i.e. turn your mysql date into a time value with [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime), then reformat it with [strftime](http://php.net/strftime).

However this only works for dates which can be represented by a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) - so no dates before 1st Jan 1970 or after [2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem)

### Using PEAR's Date class...

The [PEAR Date classes](http://pear.php.net/package/Date/docs/1.5.0a1/Date/Date.html) for a more thorough approach which should cope better with historical dates:

```
$date=new void Date("2009-01-27 14:30:22");
echo $date->format("%d %m %Y");
```

### ...or use your DB

Alternatively, have your db format it for you with [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
SELECT col1,col2,DATE_FORMAT(col2, '%W %M %Y') as col2readable FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer. If I am doing a select *, is it fine to put DATE_FORMAT after the *, or would I need a separate query?

Comment: no you can include it in the same query, e.g. select *,date_format(mycolumn, '%d %m %Y') as formatted_date from mytable

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with PHP, but if you don't need the additional baggage, you could consider doing it in your query and return only what you need. This example uses [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
"SELECT col1, col2, DATE_FORMAT(dateCol, '%d-%m-%Y') as 'newDate' 
 FROM tablename"
```